# struts 2 iterator with range

Tags: struts2

I have an array of strings. Lets say array[] containing 5 strings: "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
Now I want to display only strings at position 3 and 4 in the jsp file. How do I do that with s:iterator tag ? (just like a normal for loop starting at 3 and ending at 4)

Is there a way to loop with s:iterator with a begin and end value just like a normal loop ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use `iterator` tag with `begin` and `end` attributes.
Example from [Struts2 tag reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/iterator.html):

```
<s:iterator value="{1,2,3,4,5}" begin="2" end="4" >
    <!-- current iteration value (2,3,4) -->
    <s:property value="top" />
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html to see the iterator properties that are available for your use so you can create conditional statements like "if loop is at position 3 of the array, then print the value"

Alternatively, you can also try `s:subset` tag.  See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/subset.html for more info.

Comment: well, any other clean way to do this ? Do not want to go through 50 empty iterations to be able to print something on the screen afterwards ? Can't we just start at somewhere by s:iterator ?

Comment: @user801716 I forgot about Struts2 subset tag.  See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/subset.html

Comment: thank you so much! it did the work perfectly. You saved my day.

Comment: @user801716: Then mark the answer as solved (the green check mark).